QGIS automatically name a file after multiple specific attribute values
I'm trying to get an answer how to create a python code that allows me to pick multiple attributes from another file and rename the shapefile I eventually get at the end of my model in the QGIS model designer.
For example if I put in a .shp file with the name "blank.shp", another layer with polygons of a country has specific attribute fields like "Country" / "State" / "City" and the result of my modeler must be that my .shp file is automatically called (for example) USA_Ohio_Cincinnati, based on the selection I make in the beginning.

I have a Line-Input that allows me to manually select the file I'm working on. I also manually select a polygon based file which I want to use the attributes from.

I dont understand, can you add a screenshot of your model?
